# 'Unread public/protected field' FindBugs

Tags: java, findbugs

I have an abstract class which has 2 protected final fields, which are set in the constructor. The class doesn't use the fields, but all subclasses will - hence the fields are set in the superclass and are protected.

FindBugs complains with the following warning:

URF_UNREAD_PUBLIC_OR_PROTECTED_FIELD: Unread public/protected field

This field is never read.  The field is public or protected, so perhaps it is intended to be used with classes not seen as part of the analysis. If not, consider removing it from the class.

I know I can suppress the warning, but in general - is such code bad? Why does it complain in the first place? It does know it is an abstract class, i.e. meant for subclassing?

Comment: That's what _so perhaps it is intended to be used with classes not seen as part of the analysis_ means. Just ignore or suppress it.

Comment: I have this problem but am unable to suppress the warning for some reason